# In React, which value should I rely on when doing a fetch in a dropdown? the e.target value or the value from the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

what is the best practice for this kind of stuff?

```
handleChange = e => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    this.setState({ selectedOption: value });
    this.fetchrepos(value);
  };



handleChangeVersion2 = e => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    this.setState({ selectedOption: value }, () => {
      this.fetchrepos(this.state.selectedOption);
    });
  };
```

Here is the code
https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-dust-ygfos

Comment: Both will do the job for sure. `setState` is asynchronous so if you need to ensure ordering of events after a `setState` call is made, you can pass a callback function as you did in method 2. Whereas in method 1, you should rely on `value` from `event.target` instead of state.

Answer (score 6):

Neither. Each function should have a single, **clearly defined**, objective ([Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)). One to handle changes to state, another to handle side-effects like data fetching. You shouldn't couple behaviors together.

You should use one of the component lifecycle functions to pick up on the selection value updating in state and make the data fetch. `componentDidUpdate` is the one.

```
handleChange = e => {
  const { value } = e.target;
  this.setState({ selectedOption: value });
};

componentDidUpdate(prevState) {
  if (prevState.selectedOption !== this.state.selectedOption) {
    fetchRepos(this.state.selectedOption);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir!!!. what resources do you recommended to learn React Best Practices?

Comment: @ChinZhao Great question! For me it is mass consumption of react documentation, read articles on the web, read general software design articles, ... basically try to learn something new as often as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should relay on the `e.target` value  as the `setState` is an async function. But if you trigger the api call on state change then rely on state value and trigger your api call in lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done that is also better solution to fetch api as a callback of `setState()`

```
  handleChangeVersion2 = e => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    this.setState({ selectedOption: value }, () => {
      this.fetchrepos(this.state.selectedOption);
    });
  };

  async fetchrepos(searcTerm) {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=${searcTerm}`
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ data: data.items });
  }
```